# How could I make my own file extention that works on a raspberry pi from C++?

Tags: c++

How could I make my own file extention that works on a raspberry pi from C++?
I would like to make a file extention that keeps information for a custom OS for mobile devices such as phones, and tablets. what would the proper way to code an extention for this? information as in names, DOB, maybe their contacts?, and basically anything on the phone that id need to be stored permanantly. how would I do that?

Comment: File extension is unrelated to c++. Some OS link extension to (default) application to open them.

Comment: The file extension doesn't really mean anything, it's just part of the file name. You could create the file in any way you want, say XML or JSON. How do you want the file to be used though? Do you want someone to be able to double-click it on their desktop, and it opens in your program? That is a matter of putting the right settings in Windows/Linux/whatever.

Comment: What I understand is that you are looking for a way to define your own MIME type. You should have a look at https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/

Comment: @Calebisnotagoodcoder there are two meanings to your question 1. you want to somehow associate file with C++ code 2. you want a create a file type specific for your data for example mydata.raspberry where you will people contact details. Could you elaborate which one is it?

Answer (score 1):

File extensions don't really mean anything, it's just a part of the the file's name. It helps tell the operating system to what program to run with the given file. So making a file extension is quite simple, you just write your data to a file. [Here is a great example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/writing-a-binary-file-in-cplusplus) of doing it in C++

After you have your binary you can read back just as easily, I'll quote a few lines from [this site](https://courses.cs.vt.edu/cs2604/fall02/binio.html)

A file stream object can be opened in one of two ways. First, you can supply a file name along with an i/o mode parameter to the constructor when declaring an object:

```
ifstream myFile ("data.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);
```

Alternatively, after a file stream object has been declared, you can call its open method:

```
ofstream myFile;
...
myFile.open ("data2.bin", ios::out | ios::binary);
```

Either approach will work with an ifstream, an ofstream, or an fstream object.

Normally, when manipulating text files, one omits the second parameter (the i/o mode parameter). However, in order to manipulate binary files, you should always specify the i/o mode, including ios::binary as one of the mode flags. For read/write access to a file, use an fstream:

```
fstream myFile;
myFile.open ("data3.bin", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
```

To read from an fstream or ifstream object, use the read method. This method takes two parameters:

```
istream& read(char*, int);
```

The read member function extracts a given number of bytes from the given stream, placing them into the memory pointed to by the first parameter. It is your responsibility to create and manage the memory where read will place its result, as well as to ensure that it is large enough to hold the number of bytes requested. The bytes that are read and not interpreted, the method does not assume anything about line endings, and the read method does not place a null terminator at the end of the bytes that are read in.

If an error occurs while reading (for example, if you read off the end of a file), the stream is placed in an error state. If that occurs, you can use the gcount method to find out the number of characters that were actually read, and use the clear method to reset the stream to a usable state. Once a stream goes into an error state, all future read operations will fail.

An example:

```
#include <fstream.h>
...
char buffer[100];
ifstream myFile ("data.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);
myFile.read (buffer, 100);
if (!myFile) {
    // An error occurred!
    // myFile.gcount() returns the number of bytes read.
    // calling myFile.clear() will reset the stream state
    // so it is usable again.
}
...
if (!myFile.read (buffer, 100)) {
    // Same effect as above
}
```